# Saving in game progress

Tags: ios, swift

I've working on a game in Swift for iOS 8 in Xcode 6 and I need some advice on how to save my in-game progress. When i close out the app, and restart it again, I want the game to remember where i left off, rather than starting all the way at the beginning each time I open it. How can I do this. Game center? External files?

Comment: This question is too broad. How you save something depends on what and why you are saving it.

Comment: He says what and why in the question.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that [NSUserDefaults](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/index.html) could work for you. It is the easiest way to save a small amount of data between sessions. NSData, NSString, NSNumber, NSDate, NSArray and NSDictionary are supported.

Answer (score 0):

Since an iOS game might be played by the same user across different devices, maybe take a look at using `NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore` to store the game state in the user's iCloud. That way, the game will continue where left off for the user no matter which device they use.